# Unable to get the value of a MongoDB key

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

2 days old to Mongo, so bear with me.

I have a collection from which, I only want to retrieve specific values contingent to another key existing in the MongoDB environment.

Here is what I am doing:

```
db.results.find({'someKeyThatShouldExist':{$exists:true}},  {"parentKey.childKey.theKeyWoseValueIwant":1}
```

This yields data in the following format for me:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("532a2c2b6803fa486b8b456a"), "parentKey" : { "childKey" : { "theKeyWhoseValueIWant" : 102982577 }}}.....
```

Now, all I really want is the value 102982577, not everything else.
How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the _id by adding `_id:0` to the projection criteria.

```js
db.results.find(
    {"someKeyThatShouldExist":{$exists:true}},  
    {_id:0, "parentKey.childKey.theKeyWoseValueIwant":1}
)
```

To get just the value, you could do something like:

```js
db.results.find(
    {"someKeyThatShouldExist":{$exists:true}},  
    {_id:0, "parentKey.childKey.theKeyWoseValueIwant":1}
)[0].parentKey.childKey.theKeyWoseValueIwant
```

Comment: "You cannot currently mix including and excluding fields. Contact us if this is an issue"
Upon trying your strategy

Comment: @ParijatKalia  What is your MongoDB version? Or are you actually using **meteor** or something?

Comment: @ParijatKalia Doesn't explain it. You are not doing **exactly** what was given in the example. The only field you suppress is `_id` as was shown. Then you **only** include the fields you want. Do **not** supress any others. That will be the source of your error.

Comment: @ParijatKalia, please read Neil's comment above.  To quote from the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/): `A projection cannot contain both include and exclude specifications, except for the exclusion of the _id field.`

Comment: ok, can't get that to work because my keys are in quotes and it says 'Unexpected string' :(